# Manually set Authenticated Spring User

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am building a SpringBoot application.

I am using Spring Security, and have a UserDetailsService implementation setup:

```
public class MyUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User springUser = null;
        User user = userService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        if(user != null){
            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = null;
            List<Role> roles = user.getRoles();
            if(roles != null){
                authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                for(Role currentRole: roles){
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(currentRole.name()));
                }
            }
            springUser = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
        }
        return springUser;
    }

}
```

I have a service layer that contains method for adding users to the database:

```
public interface UserService {

    public Long addStandardUser(String firstName, String lastName, String username, String password);

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public Long addAdministratorUser(String firstName, String lastName, String username, String password);

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public User loadUserByUsername(String username);

    public Iterable<User> getUsers(int pageNumber, int pageSize, Direction direction, String sort);

}
```

I also have a CommandLineRunner implementation that I use (in dev mode) to  initialize the database with sample users:

```
@Component
@Profile("dev")
public class DBInitializer implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"));
        Authentication authentication =  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("foo", null, authorities);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        userService.addAdministratorUser("John", "Doe", "jdoe", "1234");
        System.out.println("done!");
    }
}
```

The trouble is that I am getting an Access Denied exception from Spring in the CommandLineRunner when I try to add the user. I'm assuming that the issue is that I am manually 'injecting' a Spring User incorrectly. The addAdminUser() method has to be run by a user in the ADMIN role, so I need to temporarily run as an ADMIN user. I know there is a @RunAs annotation that I remember using in other J2EE apps, but I'm not sure how that interfaces with a Spring application, or if that is used in a different context altogether

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Springboot Security hasRole not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946473/springboot-security-hasrole-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...
// The default role prefix starts with `ROLE_`
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
...
```

More detail please see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-common-built-in)