# @RolesAllowed in conjuction with configureGlobalSecurity jdbcAuthentication in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-security

`@RolesAllowed` does not seem to work when im using `jdbcAuthentication()`, but it works fine if I am using `inMemoryAuthentication()`. `jdbcAuthentication()` works fine if I remove `@RolesAllowed`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.
            jdbcAuthentication()
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select u.email, u.password, u.enabled from bagtag.user u where email=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.email, r.name from bagtag.user u join bagtag.role r on (r.id = u.role_id) where u.email=?")
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic()
                .realmName(REALM).authenticationEntryPoint(getBasicAuthEntryPoint()).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    }
}
```

The following `RequestMapping` does with `@RolesAllowed` but it works if I remove `@RolesAllowed`. I am getting the following error.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1510628906600,
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "exception": "org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException",
    "message": "Access is denied",
    "path": "/api/user/admin"
} 

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/user", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService us;

    @RolesAllowed(Role.SUPERADMIN)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<User> createAdmin(@RequestBody UserWrapper uw) {
       return new ResponseEntity<User>(uw.getUser(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I have tried to inspect the authenticated user with
`System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal());`

which returns

`org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@ca3b1db5: Username: test@test.dk; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: SUPERADMIN`

I have tried to remove `@RolesAllowed` and replaced the following line in the 
`http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic()`

with

`http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").hasAnyRole(String.format("%s,%s,%s", Role.SUPERADMIN, Role.ADMIN, Role.STAFF)).and().httpBasic()`

This gives me `http status 403`

```
{
    "timestamp": 1510629419006,
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Access is denied",
    "path": "/api/user/admin"
}
```

This is my two tables in my database. A user can only have a single role.

```
CREATE TABLE `role` (
   `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `role` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `user` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `enabled` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
   `last_login` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`),
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Springboot Security hasRole not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946473/springboot-security-hasrole-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution to my problem, I had to add `.rolePrefix("ROLE_");` to my `configureGlobalSecurity` method.

I am not sure why this is the solution. The default role prefix for `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` is an empty `String` according to according the documentation. So my best guess is that Spring default role prefix is "ROLE_".

If anyone knows the real explanation behind this madness please either post a comment or an answer. I would be very thanksful!

EDIT:
`@RolesAllowed` default prefix is `ROLE_` which is why you have to add `ROLE_` prefix to spring security!

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
     public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.
            jdbcAuthentication()
            .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder)
            //.rolePrefix fixed the problem
            .rolePrefix("ROLE_");           
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**")
            .hasAnyRole(String.format("%s,%s,%s", Role.SUPERADMIN, Role.ADMIN, Role.STAFF)).and().httpBasic()
            .realmName(REALM).authenticationEntryPoint(getBasicAuthEntryPoint()).and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not *The default role prefix for AuthenticationManagerBuilder is an empty String according to according the documentation.*, the problem is the default of `@RolesAllowed`.