# @Secured annotation not working for method authorization

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have my securityconfig as :

```
    package com.vaidiksanatansewa.guruji.security;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.vaidiksanatansewa.guruji.service.UserloginService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;


    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, IF(status=1, true, false) as enabled from users where username=? and status=1 ")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select users.username as username, user_role.role as role from users inner join user_role on users.role_fid=user_role.id where users.username=?  and users.status=1");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers( "/appointment/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","USER")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }


}
```

and method annotated in controller as:

```
....
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    public List<UserAll> getAll() {

        return userService.getAll();
    }


    @RequestMapping("/user/{id}")
    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    public UserAll getById(@PathVariable Long id) {

        return userService.getById(id);
    }
......
```

Without method authorization being enabled everthings working fine, but when it is enabled Im getting access denied error. 
It seems everything required is setup but still it isnt working.
Can you help me in spotting it out??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Springboot Security hasRole not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946473/springboot-security-hasrole-not-working)

Comment: My answer also applies for `@Secure`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It feels weird but replacing `@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")`  with `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")` did the thing. I had tried doing `@Secured("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` as well but that too didn't work. 
Well, as for now it is solved.

Comment: Same for me. I had added `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)`, and even though default value of `prePostEnabled` is `false`, `@PreAuthorize` worked