# Getting forbidden error all url in spring security (Spring boot)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have configured spring security. I have created a login form, to sign in into my application. But getting forbidden error for any authorized "USER" or "ADMIN" role based url. But all permitAll permission url working fine.

In configuration file...

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/bootstrap/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/home").hasRole("user")
            .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("admin")
            .antMatchers("/**").denyAll()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

In controller class

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value= {"/", "/index"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showHome() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/home")
    public String login() {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/admin")
    public String showDashboard() {
        return "dashboard";
    }
}
```

In login form,

```
<form class="form-signin" th:action="@{/}" method="post">
...
...
...
</form>
```

In pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

N.B. The application is compiled and run successfully, no stack trace given. Just give me forbidden error.

I can't found, where I have made an error. Please, can you help me?
  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you load your role ? What's the sql ? Do you have the role define in the database ?

Comment: I have two tables, one is, users table where the field name is username, password and enabled and another one is, authorities table where the field name is username and authority. I followed this tutorial, database part only. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxbtIqaKsOA

Comment: @Rashed Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946473/springboot-security-hasrole-not-working or it is just a typo (lower case instead of upper case)?

Comment: no, I tried both upper and lower case but didn't work. @dur

Comment: "rashed" is username and role is "admin". @chaoluo

Comment: The role name is ROLE_ADMIN or ADMIN ?

Comment: In the database, I used just admin not role_admin. @chaoluo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the default sql to load username, password and authority from database.

```
public static final String DEF_USERS_BY_USERNAME_QUERY = "select username,password,enabled "
            + "from users " + "where username = ?";
public static final String DEF_AUTHORITIES_BY_USERNAME_QUERY = "select username,authority "
            + "from authorities " + "where username = ?";
```

And role is just a authority that start with `ROLE_`, `hasRole('XXX')` is same as `hasAuthority('ROLE_XXX')`

So you can change the role name in database to `ROLE_ADMIN`,

or you can use `hasAuthority('admin')` instead of `hasRole`