# Spring Security still forbids js fetch requests when CSRF is disabled

Tags: spring, spring-security, datatables

I am adding authentication using Spring Security to a web page whose backend uses Spring Boot. When user authentication is successful, the user is redirected to the main page that has a jQuery datatable. The datatable tries to fetch its data from the server but the Ajax request gets a 403 response. I have CSRF disabled so why is the request forbidden?

Here is my security configuration:

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/resource/**").permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/*").hasRole("USER")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/*").hasRole("USER")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .successForwardUrl("/xgateUI")
                .failureUrl("/error")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/doLogout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
```

and here is the Datatable's Ajax part

```
 var table = $("#filesTable").DataTable({
        sAjaxSource: "/getAllRows",
...
});
```

The user is authenticated in

```
class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider.
```

```
List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
```

Logs show that the user is successfully authenticated.

Comment: Also your user doesn't have the role `USER`. Show your user and its roles.

Comment: The user is authenticated in class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider.
List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
Logs show that the user is successfully authenticated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946473/springboot-security-hasrole-not-working/41947532#41947532

Comment: Thanks :). This was the answer. 
grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
and
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")