# Not able to access some routes in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

This is my admin controllers which i am not able to access

```
import mis.entity.User;
import mis.services.AdminService;



@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/")
public class AdminController {
    
    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;
    
    @RequestMapping("adduser")
    public String adduser() {
        
        return "admin/adduser";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "do_register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        System.out.println(user);
        adminService.addUser(user);
        return "redirect:/admin/adduser";
    }}
```

This is happening after i configured spring security before activating spring security iwas able to access all routes.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }
     
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/new").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "CREATOR")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "EDITOR")
            .antMatchers("/delete/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            ;
}}
```

There is one more controller which i can access.
But i cant access this admincontroller i think that /admin/ is causing problem.

**Edited code in MyConfig**

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN").antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll().and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/signin")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")             
        .and().csrf().disable();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Springboot Security hasRole not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946473/springboot-security-hasrole-not-working)