Spring security 6 - authorization not working
I am using spring boot 3 and spring security 6 and trying to configure authorization but not able to get it working. I am seeing some weird behaviour which I am not able to understand.
I have configured authorization using following code
http.authorizeHttpRequests(authrorize -> authrorize.requestMatchers("/hello/**").hasRole("USER"));

but after login I get 403 Forbidden error.
I checked the spring security logs and I can see following in the logs:

2024-06-15T06:55:20.123+05:30 DEBUG 15236 --- [spring-authn-authz] [nio-8080-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.nagpal.spring_authn_authz.config.EmployeeUserDetails@2af776cf, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=846F84FABBD0F9B98EFEF4DAAE047AA4], Granted Authorities=[USER]]]

Granted authority of USER is present but I am still getting 403 error.
After some search I found that, my authorities need to be prepended by "ROLE_", so I tried to append "ROLE_" prefix to the role from my UserDetails object:
 @Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    log.info("Adding role with ROLE_ appended");
    GrantedAuthority role = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + employee.getRole());
    authorities.add(role);    
    return authorities;
}

after this change, when I try to access the endpoint, I still get 403 Forbidden error but this in logs I can see ROLE_ prefix is appended twice:

2024-06-15T06:59:28.747+05:30 DEBUG 15236 --- [spring-authn-authz] [nio-8080-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.nagpal.spring_authn_authz.config.EmployeeUserDetails@2af776cf, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=846F84FABBD0F9B98EFEF4DAAE047AA4], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ROLE_USER]]]

Here is code for EmployeeUserDetails
public class EmployeeUserDetails implements UserDetails {

private Employee employee;

public EmployeeUserDetails(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    // log.info("Adding role with ROLE_ appended");
    GrantedAuthority role = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(/*"ROLE_" + */ employee.getRole());
    authorities.add(role);    
    return authorities;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return employee.getPassword();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
   return employee.getEmail();
}

and for Employee
@Entity
@Data
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "employee_id")
private int id;
@Column
private String email;
@Column
private String password;
@Column
private String role;
}

Creating users:
public void customUsers(UserDetailsManager detailsManager) { 

    Employee employee1 = new Employee();
    employee1.setEmail("user1@email.com");
    employee1.setPassword(passwordEncoder().encode("password"));
    employee1.setRole("USER");

    EmployeeUserDetails user1 = new EmployeeUserDetails(employee1);

    detailsManager.createUser(user1);

}

Employee table after startup:

I am unable to understand this behaviour. If i don't append "ROLE_" in my UserDetails objects it does not come at all but If i configure it it comes twice.
Can someone help me understand this?

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946473/springboot-security-hasrole-not-working

By taking a closer look at Spring Security's hasRole code, you can see that it automatically adds ROLE_ to the role value for comparison.
Therefore, you need to add the ROLE_ prefix to the authorities inside the getAuthorities method.
hasRole
public AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer<H>.AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry hasRole(String role) {
    return this.access(AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasRole(role));
}

public static <T> AuthorityAuthorizationManager<T> hasRole(String role) {
    Assert.notNull(role, "role cannot be null");
    return hasAuthority("ROLE_" + role);
}

When I replicated your code, it worked correctly in my case.
Entity
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    GrantedAuthority role = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + this.role);
    log.info("Adding role : " + role.getAuthority());
    authorities.add(role);
    return authorities;
}

log
2024-06-15T14:20:01.450+09:00  INFO 22987 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] com.fixadate.global.util.LogAspect       : timeMs = 21
2024-06-15T14:20:01.450+09:00  INFO 22987 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.fixadate.domain.member.entity.Member   : Adding role : ROLE_USER

SecurityConfig
.authorizeHttpRequests((req) -> req
    .requestMatchers(PERMIT_URL_ARRAY).permitAll()
    .requestMatchers("/hello/**").hasRole("USER")
    .anyRequest().authenticated())


To help you, I'll explain how I assign roles.
You can easily grant authorities using the commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList method.
Let me explain with the code.
AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_" + role);
}

Using a comma, you can easily assign multiple roles.
For example, you can store the values USER,MEMBER in the role of an Entity. This way, the Entity will have the authorities ROLE_USER and ROLE_MEMBER.
By looking into the internal logic, you can see that it splits the string by commas and adds each as a role.
commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList
public static List<GrantedAuthority> commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(String authorityString) {
    return createAuthorityList(StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(authorityString, ","));
}

createAuthorityList
public static List<GrantedAuthority> createAuthorityList(String... authorities) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList(authorities.length);
    String[] var2 = authorities;
    int var3 = authorities.length;

    for(int var4 = 0; var4 < var3; ++var4) {
        String authority = var2[var4];
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority));
    }

    return grantedAuthorities;
}


Solution
Since unexpected issues can occur when adding or removing the ROLE_ prefix in the getAuthorities method, I resolved the problem by adding the ROLE_ prefix in the setRole method.
Employee
public void setRole(String role) { 
    this.role = "ROLE_" + role; 
}

I'm so happy that this issue is resolved.
have a nice day - kevin

In my case, I created an entity with a field named "role" and saved it.
When creating the entity, I assigned values such as USER and ADMIN to the role field.

Although it is not the recommended approach, you can add the "ROLE_" prefix when setting the role.
    this.role = "ROLE_" + role;
    }```

Then, you no longer need to add the "ROLE_" prefix in the getAuthorities method.

It worked. While creating the user I added ROLE_ prefix to role name and now it's saved as ROLE_USER in database and removed the prefix from getAuthorities method. Question, Is that what spring expects(role in database to be prefixed ROLE_)?. You can write this as answer and I can accept it for benefit of others.

I'm not entirely sure if this is what Spring expects. However, adding the ROLE_ prefix to roles in the database is one approach, and there are certainly other methods available. It's best to compare various methods to find the optimal one.
I will add this to my previous answer.
I'm very glad that the problem is resolved.
Have a nice day - Kevin
